# Continuous color for palette

Tags: java, c++

Normally I create colors with red, green, blue. However I want the user to pick colors simply with the scrollwheel, thus cannot let the user specify the three colorchannels.

I have a variable that can increment to 256 * 256 * 256.

However if I use bitshift to get the colorchannels I get sudden "jumps" in the color.

How do I get the colorchannels in a way I have a continuous color palette for the integer?

Comment: Do you want to be able to select all 16 million colours with a single control? Or is it only a subset you're interested in?

Comment: In a sense all colours, although a subset would also be okay. I was going to check for scrollspeed to switch through colours faster.

Comment: I can't think of an intuitive way to do it, as you've got several different degrees of freedom to play with. If you only wanted a base colour and not an arbitrary RGB value, I'd use HSV and scroll through hue values.

Comment: That'll do :) If you put it as answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: I suspect you'll either need to allow the scroll wheel to move multiple independent selectors one at a time, or you'll have to restrict the number of colors to an impractical amount.

Comment: @MarkRansom I figured you could treat it like the dial on a safe and modify a different thing every time you change direction. It'd be horrible though.

Comment: But of course if @JasonD is correct and all you want to modify is the hue, the restricted number of colors won't be a problem.

Comment: @JasonD, it would be worse than horrible, it would be totally unusable. Way to think out of the box though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of an intuitive way to do it, as you've got several different degrees of freedom to play with. If you only wanted a base colour and not an arbitrary RGB value, I'd use HSV and scroll through hue values.

Answer (score 1):

You have a cube that you want to walk over linearly and continuously.

Fortunately, there is no need for the inverse image to be continuous!

If you look here: http://xkcd.com/195/ you'll see a way to walk over a 2 dimensional space linearly and continuously.  Changing this walk to a 3 dimensional one isn't fundamentally tricky.

We have 2x2 cube with 8 locations, encoded as 000 through 111:

```
000 001
010 011

100 101
110 111
```

these being the coordinates of the top and bottom slices of the cube.

We walk it in this order:

```
    1 -> 2
         |
         V
/-- 4 <- 3
|
|   6 -> 7
|   ^    |
|   |    V
\-> 5    8
```

which results in us exiting the cube at the "far corner".

Now, to increase the size of the cube by a factor of two in each dimension, simply take each of the above 8 corners with the same algorithm.

8 layers deep, and we are walking a 256 x 256 x 256 cube in a continuous manner.

Now, I in practice, this might be a bad idea -- but it might be fun to try.  :)

There is a relatively simple pattern to the bit values of the locations in order:

```
000
001
011
010
110
100
101
111
```

Ie, 0102101 is the bits that are changed in the coordinate.

Or another way of looking at it, is that the way we walk the dimensions is in a Gray code pattern.